# What's the difference between 要 and 想 for "to want"?

Tags: word-choice

Is one more common ([要](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A6%81#Definitions) vs [想](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%83%B3#Chinese))? Are there different situations to use each?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where I'm from, people usually say `想要`. `想` is more for "to think", and `要` has a flavor of "to need/require", though it really all depends on the context. `想要` mixes the two meanings, kind of like "to want" has both "desire" and "necessity".

> 我渴了，我想要喝水。

*I am thirsty. I want/need to drink water.*

> 我要上這門課才能畢業。

*I need to take this course to graduate.*

> 這道菜看起來好好吃，我想點這道菜。

*This dish looks delicious. I want to order this dish.*

> 你想不想一起去北京？

*Do you want to go to Beijing?*